# Create Assembly fails because methods are not visible - but everything is public

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I'm trying to reconfigure a CLR stored procedure that used to be one big database project into a core logic project and a database project to separate my concerns. So the projects are architected like so:

```
  \src
     \Company.Core
         \CoreCode.cs
         \CoreCode2.cs
     \Company.Database
         \Programmability\Stored Procedures
             CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure.cs
             ClrStoredProcedure2.cs
```

When I try to deploy the project, I get a series of error messages:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'MyAssembly' failed because assembly "MyAssembly" failed 
verification. Check it the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for 
external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR verifier error messages if any 
will follow this message.
MyAssembly.Programmability.Stored_Procedures.CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure::.ctor Method is 
not visible.
MyAssembly.Programmability.Stored_Procedures.CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure::
.ExecuteCmsSelectQuery Method is not visible.
(Many more of these)
```

The ClrStoredProcedure1.cs contains this code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security;
using Company.Core;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;


[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers(PartialTrustVisibilityLevel = PartialTrustVisibilityLevel.VisibleToAllHosts)]


namespace KK.Corporate.ServerGroupQuery.Database.Programmability.Stored_Procedures
{
    public class CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure
    {
        public static CmsDataService _cmsDataService;

        public CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure()
        {
            _cmsDataService = new CmsDataService();
        }

        const string InitialCatalog = "master";
        const int ConnectTimeout = 10;

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void ExecuteCmsSelectQuery(string targetGroup, string query, string targetGroupUserName, string targetGroupPassword)
        {/*etc*/}
    }
}
```

These methods are public and I'm using an assembly attribute to make them more visible. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definite issue is that the constructor method -- `CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure()` -- can't / won't ever be called since it is an instance method and these classes are never instantiated. You would need to use a static constructor in the form of:

```cs
    static CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure()
    {
        _cmsDataService = new CmsDataService();
    }
```

---

The other piece might be that the method attribute for `SqlProcedure` might need to include the parenthesis. Meaning, use this:

```cs
[SqlProcedure()]
```

instead of this:

```cs
[SqlProcedure]
```

---

Also, it is best to use the `Sql*` types for input parameters / output parameters / return types for SQLCLR methods. Meaning, use `SqlString` instead of the regular C# `string`.

```cs
public static void ExecuteCmsSelectQuery(SqlString targetGroup, SqlString query, SqlString targetGroupUserName, SqlString targetGroupPassword)
```

And then access the .NET type of that parameter via the `.Value` property that they all have:

```cs
targetGroup.Value
```

---

Also, do you really need a static variable? That will require the Assembly to be marked as `UNSAFE` unless it is also declared as `readonly`.

There is good reason for this restriction: there is one AppDomain per Database per Assembly-owner. Meaning, all sessions that are calling this code concurrently will be accessing the exact same reference of that (or any) static variable. The execution context is not per sessions, it is shared across all sessions at the same time.

---

Also, the namespace name itself *might* be an issue. I generally never use namespaces for SQLCLR code since they need to be embedded into the class name portion of the `AS EXTERNAL NAME` clause of the CREATE object statement. For example, I am guessing that your stored proc would end up being:

```
[MyAssembly].[KK.Corporate.ServerGroupQuery.Database.Programmability.Stored_Procedures.CmsSelectQueryStoredProcedure].[ExecuteCmsSelectQuery]
```

I haven't tried that length or with multiple periods and underscores, so it might be just fine.

---

For more info on working with SQLCLR, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read articles on that site; I have no control over that policy):

[Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)

Comment: Ah the constructor - rookie mistake! I still wonder why I'm getting all these "Method is not visible" messages.

Comment: Not sure about that yet because so far everything _looks_ fine. that is why I mentioned the namespace, only because nothing obvious is jumping out.

Comment: I would fix the constructor issue first and recompile. If you are still getting the error, maybe try a simpler namespace name, or none at all?

Comment: @CBauer I added a few more suggestions. But I think the visibility issue might simply be a matter of missing parenthesis on the method attribute.

Comment: Sorry I've gone dark here, but now I'm getting "unable to resolve token" and I'm trying to get around that before I make anymore major changes

Comment: @CBauer Not a problem. You need to at least take care of the first two things I mentioned. And if you are still set on doing the static variable, hence needing the Assembly to be `UNSAFE`, do you in fact mark it as `UNSAFE`? If not then you could get errors like "unable to resolve token", so it will need to be marked as such.

Comment: I removed the static variables and am now instantiating them inside the sqlprocedure methods.

Comment: @CBauer Good choice :-)

Comment: I don't know exactly what happened here, but after making the changes you suggested I had a lot of problems with strange error messages. I did a DROP DATABASE on my local copy and reran the database deploy script, then targeted my local with the schema compare update command and it just worked, so I'm going to say that the suggestions above fixed it. Seems like you post a lot about SQL CLR, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @CBauer No problem. Glad to help. I forgot to add this yesterday so I just updated my answer with a link at the bottom to a series I am writing on this topic :-).